# Qt C++ - Can't compile after switching to 64-bit

Tags: c++, qt

Recently, I realized that I was running a 32-bit version of Ubuntu, even though my computer was capable of 64-bit, so I upgraded from 12.10(?) 32 bit to 15.10 64 bit.

Qt did not like this at all. When compiling any project, I would get this:

```
error: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory compilation terminated.
```

I fixed this with:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib g++-multilib
```

, but now I get

```
error while loading shared libraries: libQt5Widgets.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
```

After some research, I found that that's the result of compiling a 32-bit program on 64-bit libraries.

I'm not trying to cross-compile from 32 to 64, I just want to compile it on my computer.

Comment: Did you get the 64 bit version of Qt after you upgraded?

Comment: "libQt5Widgets.so.5: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64" - that's a 64-bit library. If you have a 32-bit version, it is probably in the wrong place/not found first.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, thanks to NathanOliver and Mats Petersson (thanks!).

What I did was I went into the Projects tab on the right, and clicked Manage kits at the top.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1erZ0.png)
In the kits tab, select the default configuration, and then look at the compiler combo-box. Make sure that you select a 64-bit compiler, and not a 32-bit one.

Now, rebuild all, clean all, and run qmake in the Build tab of the menu bar, and you should be able to compile your program.